# What is "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sfProductFilter'"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul.productSmall").sfProductFilter();
        alert("jQuery is working fine!");
});
</script>
```

I have above script in my site and if I place alert before following line it works well.

```
$("ul.productSmall").sfProductFilter();
```

Otherwise it does no work. I checked it in chrome and found following:

[image: Uncaught Error Screen Shot]

It seems method could not found but I have it in my /js/plugins.js file.

Comment: if you are talking about top two lines in screenshot, these are just taken from HTML5Boilerplate by Paul Irish.

Comment: If it works with the alert I would suggest the deferred load is the issue, does it work without deferring plugins.js?

Comment: @mgraph - It isn't loading it twice. First it tries to load it from Google and if that didn't work it loads the site-local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because `sfProductFilter();` is a plugin and your plugin script is set to `defer` loading? (Placing an alert before the problem line perhaps gives the plugin script enough time to load.) Try updating your script elements to not include the `defer`...

Comment: I placed these lines to script.js but it does not work either
$("ul.productSmall").sfProductFilter();
        alert("jQuery is working fine!");